# Establish the dispersion relation ω = ω(k)

Tags: partial-differential-equations, physics, wave-equation, electromagnetism

[image]

Stuck on this question, need help.

Answer:   w = ck

Comment: Is the left hand site of the equation equal to $\frac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial r^2} + \frac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial t^2}$? I'm a little bit confused since this is not the wave equation I have in mind.

Comment: @Jan the LHS is the Laplace of $\Phi$, i.e. $\operatorname{div}(\operatorname{grad}(\Phi))=\Delta \Phi = \nabla^2 \Phi$

Comment: @Botond Yes, so I am right with my thought?

Comment: @Jan No. Here, $r$ is the position vector, i.e. an $n$-dimensional (usually $n=3$) vector. So it's $\partial_x^2 \Phi+\partial_y^2 \Phi+\partial_z^2 \Phi$, and there is no time derivative.

Comment: @Botond And that is the point I don't understand. $\phi$ is also a function of $t$. As I learned, the gradient contains all partial derivatives, which would lead me to the time term too.

Comment: @Jan Yes, it might be confusing for a mathematician at first. Usually, the space and time dimensions are treated separately (it is not in special relativity!). So, the gradient, curl, divergence, etc. is usually acting on the "space part" only. But there is the d'Alambert operator, $\Box=\partial_x^2+\partial_y^2+\partial_z^2-\frac{1}{c^2}\partial_t^2=\nabla^2-\frac{1}{c^2}\partial_t^2$, which has the time derivative in it as well. (You might find it multiplied by $-1$ or $c^2$ or $-c^2$ elsewhere, but it does not really matter)

Answer (score 1):

Just substitute
$$\Phi=\Phi_0 \exp[i(kr-\omega t)]$$
to the equation, take the derivatives and simplify.

Comment: Where did the complex number i appear from?

Comment: @Mathematica It will cancel out at the end; it's just a convention, because that's the plane wave has that form. But you will get the same result with $\Phi_0\exp(kr-\omega t)$ as well.

Comment: Thanks!........

Comment: @Mathematica You are welcome! Did you get that $\omega^2=c^2|k|^2$?

Comment: Yh, got it in the end! Easier than it looked.